# It is possible to generate circles with text without overlapping in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Like in question, I'm looking for algorithm to generate circles without overlapping in other circle. I mean I have one circle (radius = 300px) and I want to random 5-6 other circles with text in this circle

Comment: can you provide with an example or your code?

Comment: There are libraries like (w/FitText.js): http://circletype.labwire.ca/ If you have something more specific or that doesn't work, ask a more specific question with what you've tried.